# Phalcon: Convert MySQL data types to PHP data types and vice-versa

Tags: phalcon

What is the best way to handle datatype conversion between MySQL and PHP while using Phalcon models. When a datetime field is retrieved from MySQL, it is converted to a string which I want to automatically convert to datetime. Similarly for MySQL decimal fields, I want to convert the value to a custom Decimal field.

So, where exactly does this datatype conversion happen? OR if it does not, what's the best way to achieve this kind of data conversion? I went through the documentation but couldn't find anything relevant to this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to handle this that I know of.

One is using model annotations to describe metadata:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#annotations-strategy

This will solve your issue with decimals but not with datetime it sounds like.

The other is by using an afterFetch hook to mutate the model:

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#initializing-preparing-fetched-records